# Parsing HTTPS instead of HTTP in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, https

I know how to parse HTTP requrests using Net::HTTP. How do you parse HTTPS requests?

I've tried and it says as a response (one of the lines):

```
<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head>
```

stox

Edited:

So to show you in a little bit more detail:

For example, here is the HTTP API

```
https://xxxxx.info/merchant/balance?password=$main_password
```

How do I use Net:http to run this? Or do I use something else?

Thanks
Stox

Comment: It looks like the request came in on port 443 but came as a standard http request instead of https.

Answer (score 16):

would be helpful if you showed us some code?

try setting these attributes

```
# assuming http is generated like this http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
# might need this as well? 
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that by setting `use_ssl` to `true` before executing the request.

```
uri = URI(https://xxxxx.info/merchant/balance?password=$main_password)
res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, use_ssl: true) do |http|
  http.request(req)
end
puts res.body
```

reference https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-HTTPS